# how to put double quotes key as varaible in json query

Tags: ansible

I need to put double-quoted key as variable in JSON query. It works fine if I put key string directly with backslash, But doesn't when I used it as variable

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    cert: |
      {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "data": {
            "ca.crt": "xxxx",
            "tls.crt": "yyyyy",
            "tls.key": "zzzzz"
        }
 
      }
    cert_type: "ca.crt"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        #msg: "{{cert|from_json|json_query('data.`{{cert_type}}`')}}"  ## Does not work 
        msg: "{{cert|from_json|json_query('data.\"ca.crt\"')}}"   ## works
```

Comment: I think the problem is double, one apart of the escaping of quotation due to the usage of python code in json_query() (who use . internally) it might also need to escape in that JSON the dot (.) it's used to call any data on the JSON Object.

Ex.: [*].ca.crt in jq would get that information, but how to tell that ca.crt is not part of the JSON structure and it's one specific node.

Comment: Did small correction in my code. The does not work line should contain varaible {{ cert_type}} instead of ca.cert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never nest Jinja `{{...}}` template markers. When you write this:

```
msg: "{{cert|from_json|json_query('data.`{{cert_type}}`')}}"  ## Does not work
```

You are looking for the literal string `{{cert_type}}`. You want to perform variable interpolation, which might look something like this (using Jinja's string concatenation operator):

```
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{cert|from_json|json_query('data."' ~ cert_type ~ '"') }}
```

Or this (using Python-style `format` method):

```
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{cert|from_json|json_query('data."{}"'.format(cert_type)) }}
```

Given your example playbook, both of the above tasks result in:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "xxxx"
}
```